# Converting date 24-NOV-49 to yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, type-conversion, date-conversion

I am trying to convert the date `24-NOV-49` to `1949-11-24`.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
TRY_CONVERT(DATE, NULLIF(GEB_DATUM,''), 103)
```

Unfortunately this is giving me wrong conversions:

```
DATE        WRONG CONVERSION         SHOULD BE 
24-NOV-49   2049-11-24               1949-11-24
01-MEI-62   NULL                     1962-05-62
05-DEC-71   NULL                     1962-12-05
```

Comment: How do you know if 30-APR-19 should be 1919-04-30 or 2019-04-30?

Comment: SQL server expects that the date are in the correct/known format. Before this line do `SET DATEFORMAT dmy ` See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Without clearing @Jarh doubt,how you can get correct answer.

Comment: How do you get 1962 for the third date?  Clarify the rules.  Do you always want the 1900s?  Or do you want 2000s for some dates?

Answer (score 3):

The default cut-off on two digit years for SQL Server is 50 so anything before this is moved to the current century and anything after into the previous one.
You can change the default [and instructions are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-two-digit-year-cutoff-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)

More likely though you'll need to handle it manually, break the string into year, month and day, apply logic to get the right numerical values and then build it up again with DATEFROMPARTS.

Answer (score 0):

You may configure the Server properties of the-two-digit-year-cutoff-server-configuration-option as below:

Then try execute the below statements:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE,ISNULL('24-NOV-49','')),23);
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE,ISNULL('05-DEC-71','')),23);
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE,ISNULL('01-MAY-62','')),23);
```

[image: Two-digit-year-cutoff Server Configuration]

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-two-digit-year-cutoff-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017